# ¿Para qué sirve colocar "= null" en una sentencia?

Tags: sql-server

Una pregunta teórica, pero pregunta al fin.

Se utiliza el `is null` y `is not null` para comprobar si un campo es nulo, pero hoy como acto fallido coloqué `where columna = null`. La consulta no me arrojó ningún resultado (lo cual me sorprendió ya que estaba seguro que habían 2 campos nulos para esa columna), y al colocar `is null` me mostró los dos resultados esperados.

Supongo que si no hay error de compilación es porque `= null` tiene algún significado.

¿Qué significa y para qué se utiliza?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es parte del estándar SQL:

En el punto 8.2 de la especificación de SQL92, se define un ***Predicado de Comparación*** como:
Un ***Constructor de Valor de Renglón*** seguido de un ***Operador de Comparación*** seguido de otro ***Constructor de Valor de Renglón***.

El ***Operador de Comparación*** puede ser: `=` ó `<>` ó `<` ó `>` ó `<=` ó `>=`.
Un *Constructor de Valor de Renglón* puede ser -entre muchas otras cosas definidas en el punto 7.1- simplemente `NULL`.

La regla número 1 establece:

> 1) Sean X y Y dos cualesquiera <Constructor de Valor de Renglón> correspondientes. Sean XV y YV los valores representados por X y Y, respectivamente.
>
> Caso:
> a) Si XV ó YV es valor nulo, entonces "X <Operador de Comparación> Y" es desconocido.

Sin embargo, así como se establece claramente una regla para comparación de valor nulo, no existe regla o restricción alguna que considere un error de sintaxis `= null`, quedando a criterio de los implementadores del estándar su significado particular.

En otras palabras, el estándar lo permite mas no lo define.

Answer (score 5):

Es algo propio de la especificación Transact-SQL, como bien dice la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Para determinar si una expresión es `NULL`, utilice `IS NULL` o `IS NOT NULL` en lugar de los operadores de comparación (como `=` o `!=`).
> Los operadores de comparación devuelven `UNKNOWN` si uno de los
> argumentos o ambos son `NULL`.

Ese es el motivo por el que no se usan operadores de comparación para determinar si un valor es nulo o no. Lo que se busca al usar `IS NULL` o `IS NOT NULL` es un resultado booleano (verdadero o falso) que indique si el valor evaluado es o no nulo.

Como podrás en el apartado [NULL y UNKNOWN (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): `NULL` y `UNKNOWN` (desconocido) no es lo mismo:

> Cuando hay valores `NULL` en los datos, los operadores lógicos y de
> comparación pueden devolver un tercer resultado `UNKNOWN`
> (desconocido) en lugar de simplemente `TRUE` (verdadero) o `FALSE`
> (falso). Esta necesidad de una lógica de tres valores es el origen de
> muchos errores de la aplicación. Los operadores lógicos en una
> expresión booleana que incluya valores `UNKNOWN` devolverán `UNKNOWN`
> a menos que el resultado del operador no dependa de la expresión
> `UNKNOWN`.

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar un valor `NULL` debes usar `IS NULL` no  es vàlido usar `= NULL` ya que en este caso:

```
where columna = null
```

indica que la expresión `columna = NULL` significa que "el valor de la columna es igual a algo desconocido", no va a marcar algùn error pero no funcionarà para el objetivo deseado.

> La condición `IS NULL` se usa en SQL para probar un valor `NULL`. Devuelve
> VERDADERO si se encuentra un valor `NULL`; de lo contrario, devuelve
> FALSO.

Como ejemplo la siguiente tabla `Personas` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si realizamos una consulta de los registros donde el valor del campo `favorite_website` sea NULL lo realizamos de esta forma:

```
SELECT *
FROM Personas
WHERE favorite_website IS NULL
```

Se tendrà como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio si deseamos realizar una consulta de los registros donde el valor del campo `favorite_website` no sea NULL lo realizamos de esta forma usando `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Personas
WHERE favorite_website IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: muy buena tu respuesta y completa, pero no resuelve la duda de para que sirve el = null, ya que no saltó ningún error como cuando hay algún error de compilación

Comment: aun estoy editando gracias